# a strange regular on look behind

Tags: java, android, regex, lookbehind

i write a piece of program to fetch content from a string between ":"(may not have) and "@" and order guaranteed，for example a string like "url:123@my.com",the I fetch "123",or "123@my.com" then i fetch "123" ,too; so I write a regular expression to implement it ,but i can not work,behind is first version:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=:?).*?(?=@)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("sip:+8610086@dmcw.com");
if (matcher.find()) {
     Log.d("regex", matcher.group());
} else {
     Log.d("regex", "not match");
}
```

it can not work because in the first case:"url:123@my.com" it will get the result:"url:123"
obviously not what i want:

so i write the second version:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=:??).*?(?=@)");
```

but it get the error,somebody said java not support variable length in look behind;

so I try the third version:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=:).*?(?=@)|.*?(?=@)");
```

and its result is same as the first version ,BUT SHOULD NOT THE FIRST CONDITION BE CONSIDERED FIRST?

it same as

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?(?=@)|(?<=:).*?(?=@)");
```

not left to right! I consider I understood regular expression before ,but confused again.thanks in advance anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (slightly edited, see comments):

```
String test = "sip:+8610086@dmcw.com";
String test2 = "8610086@dmcw.com";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+?:)?(.+?)(?=@)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
matcher = pattern.matcher(test2);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
+8610086
8610086
```

Let me know if you need explanations on the pattern.

Comment: it works well!thank you a lot!and I change it to Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+?:)?(.+?)(?=@)"); and work well,too.

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, you change makes sense: the \\+? part is useless unless followed by something more specific than .+? (for instance \\d+?).

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can't do a variable lookbehind in java.

Then, you can do something like this, you don't need lookbehind or lookaround.

Regex: `:?([^@:]*)@`

[Example](http://regex101.com/r/bE2gK4) In this example (forget about \n, its because of regex101) you will get in the first group what you need, and you don't have to do anything special. Sometimes the easiest solution is the best.

Comment: it seems reasonable,but I exam it and it fails,I put you regex into my pattern ,but the :? part seems not effect at all ,I am confused,too.thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need any look-aheads or look-behinds here. What you need can be accomplished by using a a greedy quantifer and some alternation:

```
    .*(?:^|:)([^@]+)
```

By default java regular expression quantifiers (`*+{n}?`) are all greedy (will match as many characters as possible until a match can't be found. They can be made lazy by using a question mark after the quantifier like so: `.*?`

You will want to output capture group 1 for this expression, outputting capture group 0 will return the entire match.

Comment: I exam it,not work well.  .*(?:^|:) part not work well in my pattern.thanks anyway.